# Retrieving the label name for a custom fields in backend product tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product

Below is the WooCommerce Custom Product with custom field, custom tab and it's content:

I'm sampling the first text field at this tab. **Goal is to get the "label" property of these fields.**

```
function launch_product_tab_content() {
    global $post;
    ?><div id='launch_contents' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'><?php
        ?><div class='options_group'><?php
            woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
                'id'            => '_text_announced',
                'label'         => __( 'Announced(Global)', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'      => 'true',
                'description'   => __( 'Year and Month it was announced global', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'          => 'text',
            ) );

            woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
                'id'            => '_text_announced_ph',
                'label'         => __( 'Announced(Philippines)', 'woocommerce' ),
                'desc_tip'      => 'true',  
                'description'   => __( 'Year and Month it was announced global', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'          => 'text',
            ) );

            woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
                'id'            => '_text_availability_ph',
                'label'         => __( 'Availability(Philippines)', 'woocommerce'),
                'desc_tip'      => 'true',
                'description'   => __( 'Schedule date of availability in the Philippines', 'woocommerce' ),
                'type'          => 'text',
            ) );
        ?></div>
    </div><?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'launch_product_tab_content' );
```

This is what it looks like at the Product editor page, Custom Product at Wordpress:

[image: WooCommerce Custom Tab with Custom Text Field]

Now, using ACF, I used this code:

```
<?php
    $field_key = "_text_announced";
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $field = get_field_object($field_key, $post_id);
echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];


                        ?>
```

tried also the `echo var_dump($field);`

[image]

Someone said that the WooCommerce project is not binded to ACF object? That's why I can't access the WooCommerce object via ACF? Your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: what you want to do? Sorry but I cannot able to understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: Where does ACF come in here? I don't even see it being used.

Comment: @RaunakGupta I just want to access the "label" property of a custom text field of WooCommerce via Advanced Custom Fields

Comment: @staypuftman I did use. 

$field_key = "_text_announced";
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $field = get_field_object($field_key, $post_id);
echo $field['label'] . ': ' . $field['value'];

Comment: I'm not well versed with ACF but I think `woocommerce_wp_text_input` in [WooCommerce methord](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_wp_text_input.html#14-75) So you can not access params directly, you can try in this way create an `array` and then pass that array in `woocommerce_wp_text_input` and ACF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **UPDATE (A WORKIG SOLUTION TO SAVE AND RETRIEVE YOUR LABELS NAMES)**

I Have make some changes In your code **adding hidden imput fields with your label names.** When saving/submitting the data, **it will save also automatically the label names.**

Here is the complete code:

```
// ADDING A TAB TO WOOCOMMERCE PRODUCT DATA METABOX
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'launch_product_tab_content_tab' , 99 , 1 );
function launch_product_tab_content_tab( $product_data_tabs ) {
    $product_data_tabs['launch'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Launch', 'my_text_domain' ),
        'target' => 'launch_contents',
    );
    return $product_data_tabs;
}

// ADDING A FIELDS INSIDE THE TAB IN WOOCOMMERCE PRODUCT DATA METABOX
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'launch_product_tab_content' );
function launch_product_tab_content() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    // Setting here your labels
    $label_text_announced       = __( 'Announced(Global)', 'woocommerce' );
    $label_text_announced_ph    = __( 'Announced(Philippines)', 'woocommerce' );
    $label_text_availability_ph = __( 'Availability(Philippines)', 'woocommerce' );

    ?>
    <div id='launch_contents' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'>
        <div class='options_group'>
    <?php

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'            => '_text_announced',
            'label'         => $label_text_announced,
            'desc_tip'      => 'true',
            'description'   => __( 'Year and Month it was announced global', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'          => 'text',
        ) );

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'            => '_text_announced_ph',
            'label'         => $label_text_announced_ph,
            'desc_tip'      => 'true',
            'description'   => __( 'Year and Month it was announced global', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'          => 'text',
        ) );

        woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
            'id'            => '_text_availability_ph',
            'label'         => $label_text_availability_ph,
            'desc_tip'      => 'true',
            'description'   => __( 'Schedule date of availability in the Philippines', 'woocommerce' ),
            'type'          => 'text',
        ) );

        // Addind hidden imputs fields for your labels
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="text_announced_label" name="text_announced_label" value="'.$label_text_announced.'" />
        <input type="hidden" id="text_announced_ph_label" name="text_announced_ph_label" value="'.$label_text_announced_ph.'" />
        <input type="hidden" id="text_availability_ph_label" name="text_availability_ph_label" value="'.$label_text_availability_ph.'" />';

    ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// SAVING THE FIELDS DATA from THE TAB IN WOOCOMMERCE PRODUCT DATA METABOX
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_launch_product_tab_content' );
function save_launch_product_tab_content( $post_id ){

    // Saving the data with the hidden data labels names

    if(isset($_POST['_text_announced'])){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_announced', $_POST['_text_announced'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_announced_label', $_POST['text_announced_label'] );
    }

    if(isset($_POST['_text_announced_ph'])){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_announced_ph', $_POST['_text_announced_ph'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_announced_ph_label', $_POST['text_announced_ph_label'] );
    }

    if(isset($_POST['_text_availability_ph'])){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_availability_ph', $_POST['_text_availability_ph'] );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_availability_ph_label', $_POST['text_availability_ph_label'] );
    }

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**Once submitted (SAVED)** all the data is set in **`wp_postmeta`** table for the current product ID (even the label names), see below what you get in this database table *(the ID of the product is 99 here)*:

[image]

> So now you can get your label name and the corresponding data value…

**Here now a function that will automate that process and set those values in an array:**

```
function get_label_and_value($product_id, $meta_key){
    // As the meta_key of the label have the same slug + '_label' we get it here
    $key_label = $meta_key . '_label';
    
    // Getting the values
    $meta_value = get_post_meta($product_id, $meta_key, true);
    $label_name = get_post_meta($product_id, $key_label, true);

    // Setting this data in an array:
    $result = array('label' => $label_name, 'value' => $meta_value);

    // Returning the data array
    return $result;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Now we can use this function in any PHP file:

```
<?php
    // The product ID
    $product_id = $product_id;

    // The field key
    $field_key = "_text_announced";

    // Using our function
    $field1 = get_label_and_value($product_id, $field_key);

    // Displaying the data (just as you expected to do)
    echo $field1['label'] . ': ' . $field1['value'];

?>
```

And you will get:

```html
Announced(Global): April 2016
```

**So no need of ACF here**

This code is tested and works...

Comment: hi please don't delete this. I'll repky to this one yet

Comment: still the goal is to retrieve the label property declared at woocommerce custom product, with custom properties, custom text input. Because I'll be retrieving those values later on. and was hoping via ACF to retrieve those.

Comment: @RJRamirez You can't retrieve the label by any function or method as it's not stored anywhere. With the custom code you are using, this will only display the defined label with the corresponding field. So your label is just displayed, but not stored anywhere, even when you submit the product data fields…

Comment: @RJRamirez Ok, I get solution to store and retrieve your label names… See my updated answer please. thanks.

Comment: +1 thank you for this. I learned a new approach that is to save the label as a hidden field instead in the post meta. :p thank you. wondering for the next thing, I'll be adding custom data type not just a string maybe a multi-select. thanks a lot

Comment: @RJRamirez I have learned too, experimenting that hidden fields for the first time...