# Auto-populate in backend a WooCommerce Custom Product setting selector

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, product

In connection to my previous question that was successfully answered at [Retrieving WC Custom Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116037/retrieving-the-label-name-for-a-custom-fields-in-backend-product-tabs) I now have select fields and wanting also to add auto-complete custom fields(I have yet to research on this)

Questions: 
1.) How to auto-populate the custom select fields?

```
//Adding the custom field select
woocommerce_wp_select( 
array( 
'id' => '_select', 
'label' => __( 'SIM Type', 'woocommerce' ), 
'options' => array(
'one' => __( 'Regular', 'woocommerce' ),
'two' => __( 'Nano', 'woocommerce' ),
'three' => __( 'Micro', 'woocommerce' )
)
)
);

//Saving
$woocommerce_select = $_POST['_select'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );

// Display Custom Field Value
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select', true );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update:** Set programmatically the **`<option>`** in an select field:

1) You will need to store an associative array of your option key values:

```
// The associative array to store (once)
$options_array = array(
    '' => __( 'Select a value', 'woocommerce' ), // default empty value
    'one' => __( 'Regular', 'woocommerce' ),
    'two' => __( 'Nano', 'woocommerce' ),
    'three' => __( 'Micro', 'woocommerce' )
);

// Serialize the array as a string
$option_str = maybe_serialize( $options_array );

// Save this array in Wordpress options
update_option( 'my_custom_selector_options', $option_str );
```

2) Get and unserialize your selector options:

```
// Get your options select data
$select_options_str = get_option( 'my_custom_selector_options' );

// Unserialize this data:
$select_options_arr = maybe_unserialize( $select_options_str );

// Get the saved  selected 'value' if it exist
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select', true );
if( empty( $value ) ) $value = ''; // When 'value' is not defined

// 
woocommerce_wp_select(
    array(
        'id' => '_select',
        'label' => __( 'SIM Type', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => $select_options_arr,
        'value' => $value,
    )
);
```

So now your field selector options have been populated by the data that you get from WordPress options.

---

To autofill the **`woocommerce_wp_select()`**, you have to add a **`'value'`** **key** this way:

```
## 1. The select (dropdown)

// Get the 'value' data if it exist
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select', true );
if( empty( $value ) ) $value = ''; // When 'value' is not defined

woocommerce_wp_select(
    array(
        'id' => '_select',
        'label' => __( 'SIM Type', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options' => array(
            '' => __( 'Select a value', 'woocommerce' ), // Added a default empty value
            'one' => __( 'Regular', 'woocommerce' ),
            'two' => __( 'Nano', 'woocommerce' ),
            'three' => __( 'Micro', 'woocommerce' )
        ),
        'value' => $value, // <===  ===  ===  ===  ===  HERE set the 'value' key (autofill)
    )
);

## ---------------------------------

## 2. SAVING

$woocommerce_select = $_POST['_select'];
// The Default empty value is not saved (added in this condition below)
if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) || $woocommerce_select  != '' ) 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );
```

> **A quick test:**
>  
>   To see it in action, replace for example: `'value' => $value,` by `'value' => 'two',`
>   Then selected value will be: **Nano** …

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks @LoicTheAztec but What I'm asking is how to add values such as "Regular", "Nano", änd "Micro" in the selection programatically like a for loop. and how to store and get? Is it through meta also? Thank you ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll do this for default values. ;) it will still help. ;)